# Wicket quick double click submit button

Tags: java, forms, submit, wicket

I have a problem with a Wicket Form. In my form if a User click twice quickly on a SubmitLink the onSubmit method called twice and there where 2 instances of an object. How can I prevent this? I have tried using a boolean variable

```
@Override
public void onSubmit(){
  if(!submitted){
    submitted = true;
    dao.save(object);
    setResponsePage(differentPage.class);
  }
}
```

This method doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What version of wicket ?

Comment: wicket-core 7.1.0

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Your `submitted` variable should  prevent the  double submit . I am also working with the same version but i have used some indicatorbutton that will prevent from double submit for me .

Comment: There are some work around you can disable the button `onclick ` or You can use `indicator` sort of submit .

Comment: it doesn't prevent. I don't know why. What's your solution?

Comment: why not working ? Atleast disabled will work how you tried?

Comment: I don't know why not working. If i knew i didn't ask. I have the loader js too, but the quickly double click on the button avoid it and fire the event before it start

Comment: Ok let me check with my application.

Comment: Can you add how you are calling js? I have tried `boolean isSubmitted =false; if (!isSubmitted){   isSubmitted=true; //here action}` it's preventing double submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some work around To prevent double submit.

I guess you may not added renderStrategy.So first add `setRenderStrategy` in Your application class .

**Direct, IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER.** Everything is handled in one physical request. This is efficient, and is the best option if you want to do sophisticated clustering. It does not however, shield you from what is commonly known as the **Double submit problem**.

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
```

Probably above solution will work with your case. On top of that

You can disable the button on click `submit` or You can use some indicatorbutton link .

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with this lines of code

```
save_btn = new AjaxSubmitLink("submit_btn", this) {                
  protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget art){
    art.appendJavaScript("e.preventDefault();");
  }
};
```

And the

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
```

of course

Comment: Main causes of the problem renderstratergy